# Statement that implies axiom of choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Consider the following statement: for any set $E$ and $G\subseteq E\times E$, you can to get a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ where $A=dom G$, $B=ran G$ and $f\subseteq G$.

I want to show that this implies axiom of choice.

**My attempt**:I will prove that the statement above implies the existence of a choice function. Indeed, let A an arbitrary set and consider $E=\mathcal{P}(A)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ and take $G:=\{(B,\{x\})\subseteq E\times E:x\in B\}$. So, by hypotesis exists a function $f:E\rightarrow A$ that it is, in fact, a choice function.

My doubts in the proof is with the set $G$, I don't know if in your definition I use axiom of choice, because it seems that I do infinitely many choices.

Comment: Did you intend to require that (the graph of) $f$ is a subset of $G$? Without such a requirement, your statement does not imply the axiom of choice; in fact it's provable from the other axioms of set theory. The reason is that there are functions from *any* set $A$ to *any* set $B$ unless $A\neq\varnothing=B$. And that exceptional situation can't occur for you because, if the range of $G$ is empty, then so is $G$ and therefore so is the domain of $G$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, I did forget it hypothesis. It is fixed

Comment: Could you mention the source of the statement that you are proving equivalent to choice? @Gödel

Comment: @Carl: It's a fairly well-known version. I couldn't even tell you who proved that equivalence.

Comment: @Asaf: it's pretty clearly equivalent to AC, too :).  The OP must have found it somewhere - that source might be interesting for others.

Comment: @CarlMummert of course, the source is "A book of set theory" by Charles Pinter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have a problem there. Specifically, your function returns singletons of elements of $A$, not elements of $A$.

The obvious way to correct this is to take $E=A\cup\mathcal P(A)$ and $G=\{(B,x)\mid x\in B\subseteq A\}$.

Comment: It makes sense to me.

Comment: Is it not necessary delet $\emptyset$ from $E$?

Comment: No, because it is not in the domain of $G$.

Comment: Of course I see it